# Undefined Method "+" for Numeric Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, numeric

This is using tuple-space via Rinda and I have a bunch of "puts" in here to see each step happen in the console but I don't think that's very important. What IS important is when I run this section of code:

```
 while(true)

    ts.take(["empty"])

    tag, rear = ts.read( ["rear", Numeric])
    puts "11"

    value = 7
    puts "12"

    ts.write(["buf", rear, value])
    puts "13"

    puts "have some words"
    puts "14"

    tag, rear = ts.take( ["rear", Numeric])
    puts "15"

    (rear += 1) % n = rear

    puts "16"

    ts.write(["rear", Numeric])
    puts "17"

    ts.write(["full"])
    puts "18"

    end
```

I get the error:

> "undefined method `+' for Numeric:Class (NoMethodError)"

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Where specifically is that `NoMethodError` being raised? And what are you expecting `(rear += 1) % n = rear` to do?

Comment: It stops running after "puts 15" and returns the error. I expect it to add 1 to rear and then modulo n. n is defined to be 80 earlier in the code

Comment: that returns the same error. I don't think the problem is with the assignment statement, but with how the Numeric class works?

Comment: What does `puts rear.inspect` after `puts "15"` return?

Comment: it just returns: Numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1st problem

```
(rear += 1) % n = rear
```

is a funny way of writing :

```
(rear = rear + 1) % (n = rear)
```

Which means :

- increment `rear` by 1
- set `n` to `rear`
- return `rear % rear`, which is `0`

You want :

```
rear = (rear + 1) % n
```

## 2nd problem

rear is defined as `Numeric`, the [class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Numeric.html), not as a Numeric (0, 1 or 3.1415...).

Where does it come from? There's an infinite loop, so the culprit could be after the line in which you get the error.

Between `16` and `17`, you use :

```
ts.write(["rear", Numeric])
```

and that's your problem. It should be :

```
ts.write(["rear", 3.14]) # or
ts.write(["rear", rear])
```

## 3 scripts to make it work

#### 01_server.rb

```
require 'rinda/tuplespace'

URI = "druby://localhost:61676"
DRb.start_service(URI, Rinda::TupleSpace.new)
DRb.thread.join
```

#### 02_your_script.rb

```
require 'rinda/rinda'

URI = "druby://localhost:61676"
DRb.start_service
ts = Rinda::TupleSpaceProxy.new(DRbObject.new(nil, URI))

#######################################
# This needs to happen before your loop
ts.write(["rear", 0])
ts.write(["empty"])
n = 80
#######################################

loop do
  ts.take(["empty"])

  tag, rear = ts.read( ["rear", Numeric])
  puts "11"

  value = 7
  puts "12"

  ts.write(["buf", rear, value])
  puts "13"

  puts "have some words"
  puts "14"

  tag, rear = ts.take( ["rear", Numeric])
  puts "15"

  rear = (rear + 1) % n

  p "Rear is now : #{rear}"

  puts "16"

  # ts.write(["rear", Numeric]) # <- This was wrong. You don't want to write Numeric, the class.
  ts.write(["rear", rear])      # You want to write a Numeric, e.g. rear

  ts.write(["full"])
end
```

#### 03_switch.rb

```
require 'rinda/rinda'

URI = "druby://localhost:61676"
DRb.start_service
ts = Rinda::TupleSpaceProxy.new(DRbObject.new(nil, URI))

loop do
  ts.take(["full"])
  ts.write(["empty"])
end
```

#### Test

- Lauch `ruby 01_server.rb` in a terminal
- Launch `ruby 02_your_script.rb` in another terminal

It outputs :

```
11
12
13
have some words
14
15
"Rear is now : 1"
16
```

The loop stops, waiting for `"empty"`.

- Launch `03_switch.rb` in yet another terminal, and the loop repeats infinitely.

Comment: lol yeah it's a goofy way of inputting but i made it that way because i actually already tried rear = (rear + 1) % n and it returns the same damn error. Honestly I'm just going to ask my professor about it again and if he doesn't know either I'll just move on I haver other finals =.=

Comment: That was for the 2nd problem. The 1st problem is still here. How and where do you define your values?

Comment: " ts.write(["rear", rear]) "

YES this made it run well it seems! I guess rear is the name of an instance of a Numeric class and I was calling rear as the Numeric class itself previously? In any case, thanks friend!

Comment: Exactly. My pleasure, it was interesting to learn Rinda, I never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a number, you create an **instance** of the `Numeric` class (or a class that inherits from `Numeric`). The `+` method applies to instances of the `Numeric` class - it is an instance method. You are calling it on the class itself.

[Numeric](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Numeric.html) is an unusual class in that it doesn't use `new` to initialize new instances of the class. Instead numbers are created directly (you don't do `n = Numeric.new(3)` - you just `n = 3`). But the relationship between the class and the instance is the same in that the Class' class methods apply to the Class, and the instance methods (including `+`) apply to the instances.

Ruby classes can be thought of as builders or factories for instances of that class. You have in effect called `+` on the thing that creates numbers rather than on a number

Comment: Okay, that makes sense(especially after reading up on the Numeric class). What do you suggest I attempt to fix this? I've read recommendations to use something along the lines of rear.to_int but this returns a similar error (.to_int/to_i undefined)

Comment: `ts.take([Numeric])` should return a Numeric instance, and it seems to return the `Numeric` class. It doesn't make sense, at least not according to the few examples I've found.